# Confusion about EEA national section in applying for EEA family visa

Tags: visa, family, eu-spouses, uk-citizens

I am married to English person and we live in Italy. He works in Italy and I just finished my Masters. My residence in Italy is as a family member, as I am Egyptian.

We want to visit his parents and I am applying for an EEA family visa.

The question is in EEA national section. What is the information required? What is the meaning of 'Family Member of an EEA National?"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The application requests information about your spouse, since you must prove that you are the family member of an EEA national in order to qualify for the EEA family permit.  This is the part of the application where you tell them about that.

If you will be traveling with (or joining) your spouse and your residence card says "family member of a union citizen" then [you do not need an EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).

If you are not traveling with or joining your spouse in the UK then you need a [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) instead.